# What is the source for this Johannes Brahms quote?

Tags: music

Johannes Brahms reportedly said, of the Largo movement of Haydn's Symphony no. 88, "I want my Ninth Symphony to sound like that." Does anyone know to whom Brahms said/wrote this? I see multiple books that repeat the quote without attributing it.

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia entries for *Symphony No. 88 (Haydn)* in [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._88_(Haydn)) and in [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/88._Sinfonie_(Haydn)), he said it to the English composer [John Farmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Farmer_(1835%E2%80%931901)).